# Como apagar um registro com chave estrageira usando o sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize-js

Eu criei uma aplicação web usando o sequelize, minha model ficou assim:

```
const Product = db.sequelize.define('product', {
    idProduct: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: false
    },
    name: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    idCategory: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,

        references: {
            model: Category,
            key: 'idCategory',
        }
    }
})
```

Eu consigo registrar normalmente, colocando o id, nome e o id da chave estrangeira, mas quando eu tento deletar o registro  retorna um erro de constraint por causa da chave estrangeira.

Meu código para deletar:

```
app.post('/produto', (req, res) => {
    Product.destroy({ where: { idProduct: req.body.id } }).then(() => {
        res.redirect('/produto')
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.redirect('/')
    })
})
```

Como eu posso fazer para deletar um registro que se referência a outra tabela no sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

Você está passando a primaryKey e não a chave estrangeira, por isso o problema, como imagino que irá funcionar:

```
Product.destroy({ where: { idCategory: req.body.id } })
.then(() => {
  res.redirect('/produto')
}).catch((err) => {
  res.redirect('/')
})
```

Se o problema ocorre porque você precisa excluir em duas tabelas de uma vez, você vai precisar envolver isso numa Transaction do Sequelize ou ajustar a migration para que quando ocorrer a exclusão de certo registro numa tabela a outra naturalmente aplique um CASCADE.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você tenta excluir um registro da tabela principal , o Sequelize verifica se há registros associados na tabela referenciada . Se houver, o banco de dados impede a exclusão para manter a integridade referencial.
Tenta refazer a sua model desse modo:

```
const Product = db.sequelize.define('product', {
idProduct: {
    type: db.Sequelize.STRING,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: false
},
name: {
    type: db.Sequelize.STRING
},
idCategory: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    references: {
        model: Category,
        key: 'idCategory',
        // Adiciona a opção onDelete para Eliminar todas as referências
        onDelete: 'CASCADE', 
    }
}
```

});

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).